# Are there questions on the modeling of the COVID-19 epidemic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm a bit surprised that this seems to be the only spot of the Internet which hasn't been taken by storm by the COVID-19 infodemic (not necessarily a bad thing). Am I right, or has there been a raise in questions about statistical models for epidemiology lately, and I just missed them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We did have a hot network question that involved COVID-19 ([Mother milk of 6 Corona-positive (COVID-19) women does not contain the virus - can we make a confidence statement about this?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/454684/)), but it doesn't seem like too many to me, either.  I find 17 questions that [reference COVID-19](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=covid%20is%3aquestion), starting 2/16.  I find another 9 questions that [reference coronavirus](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=-covid+is%3Aquestion+coronavirus), going back a little earlier to 1/28.  It would be an issue if the site were being spammed with off topic questions, but only 4 of those 26 (15%) are closed, that's double the total proportion over that timespan (380/4514=8%), but not terrible, and not significant (p=.42) for what that's worth.